# cakePHP form errors

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

I m creating just creating a register form in cakephp.
When using the following code in my view

```
<?php echo $form->create('User', array('url' => array('action' => 'register'))); ?>
<?php echo $form->input('User.name', array('type'=>'text')); ?>
<?php echo $form->end(); ?>
```

I will get errors such as this one

```
$model = "Form"</pre><pre>sprintf - [internal], line ??
FormHelper::hidden() - CORE/cake/libs/view/helpers/form.php, line 1021
FormHelper::create() - CORE/cake/libs/view/helpers/form.php, line 214
    include - APP/views/forms/index.ctp, line 5
    View::_render() - CORE/cake/libs/view/view.php, line 662
```

Help me understand the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This also works:

```
echo $form->create('User', array('action' => 'register'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo $form->create('User', array('url' => '/users/register'));
```

Comment: Or even array('url' => array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'register')); !